# Run a Spark job for different parallelism degrees

Tags: apache-spark, scalability

I want to compare the runtime of a Spark job for different parallelism degrees in order to analyze if adding more parallelism is faster. The thing is I thought I can do it by changing the following when I am creating the Spark session:

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master(master)
      .appName(name)
      .config(conf)
      .config("spark.default.parallelism", number_of_partitions) // this is the value I change
```

But I've tried my app for `number_of_partitions = 256` and the runtime is just 1 minute faster than `number_of_partitions = 1` ! And I think it can't be.... I was expected a much big runtime when parallelism is 1. Of course the `number_of_partitions = 1` doesn't make sense in a distributed environment, but I'm getting almost the same runtime when `number_of_partitions = 16, 32, 64`.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you also mention what operation(s) you are doing? I mean transformations and actions

Comment: The performance of your job mainly depends on the data and the transformations your are doing instead of a single configuration. Can you show your code and explain how your data looks like?

Comment: It is a large job where I use multiple operations and actions, but as a summary: load data, split data using `kFold`,  apply mllib RF algorithm, etc But are you telling me there is no way to fix the desired parallelism degree? I think I missunderstood the concept, because I wanted to compare the runtime for different number of partitions or cores to see how faster it becomes if I added more resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLLib is built on the DataFrame API. Parallelism here is controlled by [parameters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) such as `spark.files.maxPartitionBytes` and `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`.

(`spark.default.parallelism` is used to control parallelism when using the RDD API).